# Spring : What is the xml version of @Controller and @RequestMapping

Tags: java, spring

I found this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12498840/difference-between-beannameurlhandlermapping-simpleurlhandlermapping)

I was wondering how is the implementation of controller in this code

```
class="org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping">
        <property name="urlMap">
            <map>
                <entry key="/hello.htm" value-ref="helloController"/>
                <entry key="/sayHello*" value-ref="helloController"/>
                <entry key="/welcome.html" value-ref="helloController"/>
                <entry key="/welcomeUser*" value-ref="helloController"/>
            </map>
        </property>
    </bean>
```

it shows sample of handlerMapping. My question is if I have only one controller, how can I map different request using those handlerMapping. If I type the hello.htm url, what method in `helloController` will it call. Same goes with the other.

Comment: With the new `<mvc:annotation-driven />` that doesn't work anymore. It works with the deprecated `DefaultAnnotationHandlerMapping`. Then it depends on how many methods there are, if there is one that will always be called, else it will take into account the `@RequestMapping` annotation. But as stated that will only work with deprecated classes with the new implementation that doesn't work anymore.

Comment: Or if it is a bean implementing `Controller` (yes the interface) there is only one method to call.

Comment: Can you give me an example of how to use DefaultAnnotaionHandlerMapping. Based on my understanding on handler mapping, one request = one controller.

Comment: I won't give you an example because it is deprecated and usage should be avoided. It will be removed in the next version of Spring. I strongly suggest a read of the reference guide on how [@MVC](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-requestmapping) works.

Comment: I already know how to implement @MVC. But the requirements in my project is not to use annotaions

Comment: Then don't use them and use the old `Controller` interface. Which has one method to implement, or use the old `MultiActionController`. But again all that is explained in the reference guide.

Comment: I guess that's my only option. Thanks.

Comment: @M.Deinum sorry to post on an old thread - but ur answer seemed to be the most authoritative. I have a similar requirement, to not use annotations. I was using spring boot, but reading ur answer it seems to me that I should be doing this through MVC or webflux. I'm happy if I have to subclass or extend classes. How would u suggest we do it in context of spring today ?

Comment: Fight the requirement, it is dumb in the current day and age and will only lead to confusion and lack of productivity.